# How to prove that $m^*(\phi)=0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm self studying measure theory and I use the book "G De Barra-Measure theory and integration".

In the text it says that lebesgue outer measure of empty set is zero. i.e. $m^*(\phi)=0$

How can I prove this ? Any help ?

Comment: Well $\emptyset \subset (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ for $\epsilon > 0$. The infimum of the lengths would be 0.

Comment: Unless you have a different definition of outer measure than royden...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extrapolate on what I commented before, according to Royden and Fitzpatrick's "Real Analysis", Lebesgue outer measure is defined as follows: $$m^*(E) = \inf\{\sum_{k=1}^\infty\ell(I_k) : (I_k)_{k\in\mathbb N} \text{ is a sequence of open intervals with } E\subseteq \cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k\},$$ where if $I=(a,b)$ then $\ell(I)=b-a$. Then we can set $I_k = (-\epsilon/2^k, \epsilon/2^k)$. The null set is a subset of any set, so $\emptyset\subset \cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$. Furthermore, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell(I_k)= \sum_{k=1}^\infty\epsilon/2^{k-1} = \frac{\epsilon}{1-1/2} =2\epsilon$. Thus the sum of the lengths of the intervals can be made arbitrarily small, so  $m^*(\emptyset)=\inf\{\sum_{k=1}^\infty\ell(I_k) :  \emptyset\subseteq \cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k\}\leq 2\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$. Therefore $m^*(\emptyset)=0$.